# Bonobo Git Server through local network?

Tags: git, iis, server, bonobo

IIS is installed on the server (web server).
So i will install Bonobo Git Server on it, but  will I be able to access my repositories from my local computer (on the same local network) ? How ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you would access any other webpage served from that server - by using a URL of the form http:/// or http:///

You could use the IP address if your server had a fixed IP address (servers usually do), or the name if your network has some way of resolving that (networks usually you).

Comment: I have tried accessing the git server on another system on the same domain, but failed to get any response. When I try to access the git server from the same system, it worked.